# How to Handle Ruined Character Type During Scraping Data with Selenium to Csv

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, utf-8

I **scraped** some reviews from a website with Selenium then, i wrote them to csv file. But some characters' type are ruined during extraction. Especially turkish characters, they cannot readable with strange characters. I formed csv file with utf-8 format. However i think there is a problem about selenium fetching part. I couldnt find character type format for selenium. How can i handle it, i am waiting for you help.. Thank you.

I used chrome driver;

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

and "find_elements_by_xpath method" for content extraction:

`container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='review-container']")`

Comment: I guess you mean “scraping” and “scraped”  - i.e. getting data by reading it from HTML web pages - rather than “scrapping” and “scrapped” - i.e. throwing away.

Comment: Are you viewing the CSV with Excel? If so, use "utf-8-sig" instead of "utf-8" as the output encoding. This adds a special character in the beginning of the file which helps Excel understand that you are using UTF-8.

Comment: it worked thank you.